# mysql trigger howto match time range from table with current time

Tags: mysql

I have following table.

```
username - start_time - endt_time
test     - 08:00:00   - 10:00:00
```

Now I want to query usernames whose start/end time is between current system. example if current time is between 0800-1000 , then print username,
(date is not involved here , only time is)

Comment: I tried this but didnt worked!
select username from test where CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN HOUR(start_time) AND HOUR(end_time);

Comment: ok finally git it------------- select username from test where CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN (start_time) AND (end_time);